# postgreSQL: insert multiple rows where only one column value changes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following queries:

```
    insert into TABLE1(a,b,c,d) VALUES('first','second','third',100);
    insert into TABLE1(a,b,c,d) VALUES('first','second','third',101);
    insert into TABLE1(a,b,c,d) VALUES('first','second','third',102);
    insert into TABLE1(a,b,c,d) VALUES('first','second','third',103);
```

`colums` `a`,`b` and `c` would always have same values across all rows. I got `100`,`101`,`102` and `103` from a `select` statement from another `table`.

```
    select id from TABLE2;        //returns (100,101,102,103).
```

Can I do this using a single query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following query allows you to insert multiple rows based on the results of a query on another table.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (a, b, c, d) SELECT 'first', 'second', 'third', id FROM TABLE2;
```

Comment: Good first SQL answer Ken.   Welcome to Stack

Comment: @Twelfth Thanks!